# I am trying to make a 4-Bit Controlled Forward Counter

Tags: logic, digital

The objective of my project is that the 4-bit counter which has a range of 0-9, counts to the desired binary number using outside dip switches then returns to the beginning again.

This is what I have come up with so far but I am a bit puzzled. How can I implement the dip switches into the circuit, also how can make it count back to zero after displaying the desired number?

Picture of simulation:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UljIS.png

Comment: 1) power----switch----ground

Answer (score 0):

To add DIP switches:

```
to flip-flop or gate input  
        |
        |
        |
power------DIP------ground
        |
        |
        |
    pull down resistor
        |
        |
        |
     ground
```

The transition back to 0 is just another state change.  Assuming the constructed the finite state machine diagram, the state-transition/truth table, and the Karnaugh maps to get the rest of the circuit, you should be able to follow the same process.